# Listing every folder and its subfolders in AWS s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 bucket with a hierarchy of folders like this:

```
Folder 1
  
  Subfolder 1
    Subsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 2
    
    Subsubfolder 2
      Subsubsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 2
  
  Subfolder 2
    Subsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 2
    
    Subsubfolder 2
      Subsubsubfolder 1
      Subsubsubfolder 1
```

I am trying to retrieve every folder and an overview of the structure within the bucket. I am currently using this code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = "Bucket_name"

response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)



for bucket in response['Contents']:
    print(bucket['Key'])
```

This is getting me the filepath of every file in the last subfolders, and is not what i am looking for. Is there any way i can list only the folders and all the subfolders within the bucket?3

Comment: Try the Prefix parameter.

Comment: The basic trick is to specify `Delimiter='/'` and the listing will come back with a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which maps to directory names. You can then recursively work through the directories.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mimic the behavior of the AWS CLI tool and other UI representations of S3, you need to pass a delimiter to any list objects call to tell S3 to group any objects with a shared prefix, and present them as something like a folder.

List objects will only return a batch of 1000 items.  To properly enumerate a bucket, you need to take the `NextContinuationToken` from the response and use it in another call till there isn't a continuation token.  boto3 has a helper function called `get_paginator` to handle this logic.

Putting it all together, you can list the objects in an S3 bucket with something like this.  This includes showing how to present the output, with a format that looks vaguely like how `aws s3 ls` works.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

def enum_s3_items(s3, bucket_name, prefix="", delimiter="/"):
    # Create a paginator to handle multiple pages from list_objects_v2
    paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    # Get each page from a call to list_objects_v2
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter=delimiter):
        # Inside of each page, return the common prefixes (folders) first
        for common_prefix in page.get("CommonPrefixes", []):
            yield common_prefix
        # And, if it's present, return each item in turn
        for s3_object in page.get("Contents", []):
            yield s3_object

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
for obj in enum_s3_items(s3, "example-bucket"):
    # This is an example of how to process the output, in reality
    # you would no doubt want to do something application specific
    # with the results.
    if 'Prefix' in obj:
        # For common prefixes, just output the name of the prefix
        # with some padding to mimic "aws s3 ls"
        print(" " * 27 + "PRE " + obj['Prefix'])
    else:
        # Grab the interesting info out of the object to mimic
        # how the cli works.
        at = obj['LastModified']
        # Conver to local time, just to mimic what the CLI does
        at = at.astimezone(datetime.now().tzinfo)
        # And pretty-print the datetime
        at = at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        # Pull out other information
        size = obj['Size']
        key = obj['Key']
        # Output to the console
        print(f"{at} {size:10d} {key}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You use prefix and you have to take care of pagination to really get all entries. So something like the above code should do the trick. This creates a generator object with all files/folders starting from prefix.

```py
def get_all(bucket_name:str, prefix:str) -> Iterable[str]:
    client = boto3.client("s3")
    paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=str(prefix))
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page.get("Contents", []):
            yield obj["Key"]

all_ = list(get_all("a_bucket", "base_folder"))
```